# Angular 6 - Modifying response body in interceptor not working

Tags: angular

I have a problem how to modify the response body with `HttpInterceptor`. Here is my code:

```
    return next.handle(modifiedReq).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            return event.clone({ body: this.modifyBody(event.body) });
        }
        return event;
    }, error => {
        this.modifyError(error);
        return of(error);
    }));

    private modifyBody(body: any) {
        //modify body here and return it
    }
```

The Interceptor is being called but unfortunately the event body is still the same after it's being modified. At `return event;` the event object has my modified body but when I jump with debugging a step forward I can see that the event is the origin one and also my services aren't working cause the expected modified body is the origin one.

I just tried to modifiy the event by changing is body like this:

```
event.body = this.modifyBody(event.body);
```

This actually works but I got an error in the angular CLI because the body-property is a constant and also in the officialy anuglar tutorials they always make clones like in my case.

So does anyone has a similiar problem or can give me any advice how to proceed here?

Comment: What happens if you withdraw your `if instanceof` ?

Comment: I update my question's code cause there was something missing. I have to use the instanceof cause otherwise I can't use .clone on the event object

Comment: `(event as HttpResponse).clone` will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just try `map` operator instead of `tap`

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html
tap will not modify result

Comment: That's it! Thanks

Comment: For the love of all that is holy, thank you. I thought I had put it as map, but apparently, I decided to do tap accidentally...